# How to store & retrieve Decimal128 values using Mongoose + Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, orm

I've already checked the other answers for this scenario on `SO`,but unfortunately non of them seem to be working for me.

I'm using the following dependencies:
**Mongoose**: ^5.11.97
**Typescript**: ^4.7.4

I have a `transactions` collection which holds the `trxValue` property whose values are in `decimal` format. I came across the new `Decimal128` type introduced in `Mongoose` and I tried implementing the same in the following way:

---

```ts
// ITransaction.ts interface file
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

export default interface ITransaction {
  trxNo: string;
  trxType: 'Credit' | 'Debit';
  trxDate: Date;
  trxDesc: string;
  trxValue: string;
  cutomerId: Types.ObjectId;
  accountId: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

```ts
// Transactions.ts model file
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import ITransaction from '../interfaces/ITransaction';

const trxSchema = new Schema<ITransaction>({
  trxNo: { type: String, required: true },
  trxType: { type: String, required: true },
  trxDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  trxDesc: { type: String, required: true },
  trxValue: {
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
    required: true,
    get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128): string => (+v.toString()).toFixed(4),
  },
  cutomerId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  accountId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
});

const Transaction = model<ITransaction>('Transaction', trxSchema);
export default Transaction;
```

---

The problem is the data types `Decimal128` don't seem to match with typescript primitive data types. I keep getting the following warning at compile time. Can somebody please give me an detailed example on how to store and fetch decimal values in `MongoDB` using `Mongoose` + `Typescript` with `precision` of **4 digits** after the decimal?

```js
Type '{ type: typeof Schema.Types.Decimal128; required: true; get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaDefinitionProperty<string> | undefined'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof Decimal128' is not assignable to type 'typeof Mixed | StringSchemaDefinition | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof Decimal128' is not assignable to type 'typeof Mixed'.
        Types of property 'schemaName' are incompatible.
          Type '"Decimal128"' is not assignable to type '"Mixed"'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: I use the `as number` casting and it works but I'm still not comfortable with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration that seems to be working for me is as follows:

```ts
import { Types, model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

interface ITransaction {
  trxNo: string;
  trxType: 'Credit' | 'Debit';
  trxDate: Date;
  trxDesc: string;
  trxValue: Types.Decimal128;
  customerId: Types.ObjectId;
  accountId: Types.ObjectId;
}

const trxSchema = new Schema<ITransaction>({
  trxNo: { type: String, required: true },
  trxType: { type: String, required: true },
  trxDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  trxDesc: { type: String, required: true },
  trxValue: {
    default: 0,
    required: true,
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  },
  customerId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  accountId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
});

const Transaction = model<ITransaction>('Transaction', trxSchema);

const trxOne = new Transaction({
  customerId: new Types.ObjectId(),
  accountId: new Types.ObjectId(),
  trxDate: new Date(),
  trxDesc: 'Description here',
  trxNo: 'avaksiw8877411',
  trxValue: '100.12258',
  trxType: 'Credit',
});

console.info(trxOne.toJSON().customerId);
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().accountId);
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().trxDate);
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().trxDesc);
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().trxNo);
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().trxValue.toString());
console.info(trxOne.toJSON().trxType);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3jmwwb?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

value: new Schema.Types.Decimal128("0.1233"),
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly related to the question, but someone who looking for `@nestjs/mongoose`, this work.

```js
import mongoose, { Types } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
---
@Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128 })
trxValue: Types.Decimal128;
---
```